# Prefer self documenting code over cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: code-quality

I'm interested in which approach to prefer. Consider some code which retrieves a translation for some text. It has to respect these constraints:

- Return translation only if the text will be used on a UI. If it's used some where else (debug log), return the normalized version of the text.
- Text normalization is costly (cpu resources). We should do it only when it is required.
- Loading the translation is costly as well.
- If translation for the text is missing or empty, return normalized original text as well.

**First approach:**

```
boolean useFallback = true;
if (textUsedForUi()) {
    final String translation = getNonEmptyTranslation(text);
    if (translation != null) {
        result.setText(translation);
        useFallback = false;
    }
}
if (useFallback) {
    result.setText(normalize(text));
}

String getNonEmptyTranslation(String text) {
    String translation = loadTranslation(text);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(translation)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return translation;
    }
}
```

**Second approach:**

```
String translation = getTranslation(text);
if (translation != null) {
    result.setText(translation);
} else {
    result.setText(normalize(text));
}

String getTranslation(String text) {
    if (!textUsedForUi()) {return null;}
    String translation = loadTranslation(text);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(translation)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return translation;
    }
}
```

**First approach** clearly documents that the translation depends on where the text will be used and if a translation is available. But I have to introduce a helper variable to avoid code duplication and not recommendable assignments in conditions:

```
String translation;
if (textUsedForUi() && (translation = getNonEmptyTranslation(text)) != null)
```

I don't want to rely on the previous value of `result.getText()`, so I can't use this as a flag whether to use the fallback or not.

The **second approach** is clearly simpler (reduced cyclomatic complexity). But it hides the dependency to where the text is used in a sub routine. This reduces the self documenting nature of the code.

Which approach to prefer?

Comment: Is it possible to return `normalize(text)` rather than null in the `getNonEmptyTranslation(String)` in the first approach?

Comment: @PEMapModder: Both approaches are eligible. The question is about which is better of both. Having ```getNonEmptyTranslation(String)``` return untranslated text will worsen self documentation of code even further.

Comment: This might be a good question for [codereview.se]

Comment: I think the first `result.setText` in the first approach is incorrect, it should set `translation` instead of `text`.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: you're right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer depends on whether `getNonEmptyTranslation` or `getTranslation` would be more generally reusable, outside of this particular piece of code. If neither are used outside of this routine, I would consider inlining the function. Apart from that you can replace the `useFallback` variable with a `return`:

```
if (textUsedForUi()) {
    final String translation = getNonEmptyTranslation(text);
    if (translation != null && StringUtils.isBlank(translation)) {
        result.setText(translation);
        return;
    }
}

result.setText(normalize(text));
```

Comment: That's a good approach. In the original code, where this problem came up, there's more code around the if block, so a return would break the code flow. But it can be refactored and extracted to a own method

Answer (score 7):

The second version is worse because the `getTranslation()` method does not necessarily do what its name indicates, but switches its behavior due to a totally unrelated factor. Confusing and misleading code is *much* worse than a few points of CC.

Answer (score 1):

The "nonEmpty" part of `getNonEmptyTranslation()` is pointless.  One could check for empty just as easy as for null.  Nor do you need a fallback variable.  So, based on that, I'd suggest

```
String translation = "";

if (textUsedForUi()) {
  translation = getTranslation(text);  // return empty if none

if (transation.length() > 0)
   result.setText(translation);
else
   result.setText(normalize(text));
```

One could shorten the code even more with tertiary operators (? :) but I think it's clearer without them.

Comment: You substituted ```useFallback``` by ```translation``` but the code is still clean and readable. Nice solution.

Comment: Thanks.  If you use this approach, you might want to rename translation to something like "validTranslation".